# internal version of a flat functor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, internal-categories

I'm working out of *Sheaves in geometry and logic*, for reference.

There is a characterisation of flat functors $A:C \to Set$ as those such that the Grothendieck construction $\int_C A$ is a filtering category. There are more general versions of this result, in which $Set$ is replaced by a more general topos. One should also be able to characterise those discrete opfibrations that arise from flat functors (up to iso/equiv?).  How about if we replace $C$ by an internal category, in a topos $E$ say? Then functors out of $C$ are replaced by discrete opfibrations over $C$ in $E$.

My question is this:

> What sort of thing should be considered as the analogue of a flat functor in the internal setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A flat internal presheaf/discrete fibration $F \to C$ is simply one whose total category F is filtered in the internal sense (see *Topos Theory* 2.51 (filteredness), 4.31 (flatness); *Elephant* B.2.6.2, B.3.2.3).  The definition just reexpresses filteredness by requiring that certain maps (e.g. $F_0 \to 1$) are regular epis (presumably you can replace these with covers for your favourite Grothendieck topology).

I *think* that if C = BG is a group then these are exactly the G-torsors in E.  I'm not sure whether this extends to flat = locally representable for C a general internal category, though.

Comment: Just to clarify, the *Topos Theory* reference here is to Johnstone's 1977 book.  Iirc it also has a couple of good exercises on this topic.